# Property in WPF Converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, converters

I Have a Grid.In the grid there are hyperlink.like Associatied,UnAssociated,Fulfill.these hyperlinks are populated through the Course status.for example if the course status is Completed and dropped.then associate link is enabled.I used converter for this.there is combobox.if the Combobox has one item then i need to hide the hyperlink assiciate.I am thinking i need to create a property in the model and can  i access the property in the converter.if yes then how?

can i use the model property and a extra check here??

```
 switch (input)
        {
            case "Associate":
                if (Course.status=="Completede" && Course.status=="Dropped")
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
```

please best solution for this????

XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Required" Width="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsRequired, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Associated}"> 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Can you post the XAML for your ComboBox and its ItemTemplate ?

Comment: 1 - Post your XAML. 2 - if you need to pass parameters to an `IValueConverter`, you have the `ConverterParameter` property of the `Binding` class

Comment: @KCS It's still unclear to me what you want to achieve. Please try to give more details

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You can use `ConverterParameter` but it is not a dependency property, hence it cannot be bound.

If you want several properties to affect the converter you should use [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is correct -- the Op is asking to bind `Visibility` against the collection of items.  There's no need for Multibinding in this scenario.